# Cannot use images in imported markdown files after updating to Angular 13

Tags: angular, webpack, markdown

Since updating to Angular 13 when I import a markdown file containing images via `markdown-loader`, images are not shown.

Situation:

- I recently upgraded my app from Angular 12 to Angular 13
- I am using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` to configure webpack
- nothing changed in my webpack config between the versions
- same version of  `html-loader` and `markdown-loader` in both

To isolate the issue, I created a new empty angular app with `ng new` on both ng12 and ng13, with following webpack config:

```js
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';

export default {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.md$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('html-loader')
          },
          {loader: require.resolve('markdown-loader')}
        ],
      }
    ],
  }
} as Configuration;
```

markdown file with image:

```
Lemon the cat

![lemon](lemon.jpg)
```

using it as follows:

```html
<div class="markdown" [innerHtml]="mdContent"></div>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import markdownFile from './markdown.md';
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private readonly sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  mdContent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(markdownFile);
}
```

Results:

- The app created with Angular 12 shows the image which has been correctly extracted in the dist files.
- The app created with Angular 13 does not show the image, the image has not been extracted, and the link points to the local path, e.g. `<img src="file:///C:/dev/workspace/labs/markdown-images/src/app/lemon.jpg" alt="lemon">`

Any idea at all about what could be causing this issue? Thank you.

Dependencies:

```json
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
      "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
      "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
      "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
      "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
      "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
      "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
      "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
      "markdown-loader": "^8.0.0",
      "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
      "tslib": "^2.3.0",
      "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.1.0",
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
      "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
      "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
      "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
      "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
      "karma": "~6.3.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
      "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
      "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
      "typescript": "~4.5.2"
    }
```

I tried to create a StackBlitz to reproduce the issue, but I can't even load MD files for some reason. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-markdown-loader

Comment: Can you add `package.json` and `angular.json` files to the question?

Comment: hi @NeNaD, have a look at the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-markdown-loader (even though the MD is not loading, it has the correct config in package.json and angular.json)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an incompatibility with the most recent versions of angular 13. Here is a package.json that works properly:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "html-loader": "~3.1.0",
    "markdown-loader": "~8.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
```

It's hard to tell which package is the cause since many are dependent on each other.

Instead of messing around with webpack and loaders, you could just bundle your markdown and images in the `assets` folder, and use `ngx-markdown`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yqzyms?file=src/assets/markdown.md

I'm getting an image from the web there, only because stackblitz doesn't let me upload images. You can change the md file to:

```markdown
Lemon the cat

![lemon](assets/lemon.jpg)
```

on your local machine.

You can also just point to a raw markdown file on github which is super handy

```html
<markdown [src]="'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...'"></markdown>
```

I'd imagine you can put images in the same repo.

It's great because you can edit the markdown file without redeploying the site.

Comment: thanks, I will try to use that list of dependencies to isolate which one is causing the issue.. I don't want to load markdown at runtime, I want it to be bundled :)

Comment: For sure, up to you. I believe images will be requested by http either way though, so what do you gain by using a loader as opposed to assets? Is it to keep the number of requests down? Just curious.

Comment: It is not about images in particular, we created a documentation app similar to storyboard (somehow) -- most of the content comes from markdown files that are transformed into html at build time. Everything is on separate libraries in the same monorepo. Number of requests/loading times is an issue. Moving single MD files out of the libs and into the asset folder of the application is also not ideal.

Comment: seems to be `"@angular-devkit/build-angular"` on v13.0.4 images work, on v13.1.0 images don't work.. soo.. something here? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#angular-devkitbuild-angular-17

Comment: Also, you can point the compiler to your libs by adding the directory names to the `assets` array in `angular.json`. I think you can use regexes as well. You would have some load times when fetching a doc for the first time, but a much smaller initial load time, since your script wouldn't be bloated with the entire library. You'd be lazy loading docs too, so much less traffic through your server.

Comment: This seems to be the only one related: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/789ddfaeb0fcbc9aab1581384b88c3618e606c4b Possibly the markdown-loader is using a deprecated function?

Comment: pffft... I tried rebuilding the devkit locally with the flag set to true and images still not showing.. it is something else I guess.

Comment: Ah, the classic bug fix side-effect. Well wish I could help more but I'm stumped. I still vote you switch to `ngx-markdown`! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade `markdown-loader` package to the version `8.0.0`. There is a **breaking change** in version `8.0.0`:

> Every call to marked is isolated now. This makes sure that options from the first call won't influence options from the second call. If you've configured the markdown-loader with two different options, you might observe different behavior now. We also removed Node v8 and Node v10 support and support for older webpack versions. Webpack 5 is required now.

Also, try to upgrade `@angular` related packages to version `13.2.x`. In version `13.2` there was a few fixes related to Webpack. You can do it with just running this command in the terminal:

```
ng update
```

Comment: I should have specified, I am already on markdown-loader 8.0.0 and html-loader 3.1.0

Comment: What version of Node.js do you have?

Comment: 16 -- also happens with 14

Comment: Can you add `package.json` and `angular.json` files in the question?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: I updated everything to latest now, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented marked.js and highlight.js for my blog which uses Angular 13.2.4. I ended up creating a markdown service that offloads the need to use that markdown-loader or need of ngx-markdown

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {firstValueFrom, from, Observable, of} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MarkdownConverterService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  convert(resourceRelUrl: string): Observable<string> {
    const parseMarkdown: Promise<string> = this.getMarkdownByPath(resourceRelUrl)
      .then(this.parseMarkdown)
    return from(parseMarkdown);
  }
  
  private async parseMarkdown(markdownString: string) {
    const marked = require('marked');
    const hljs = require('highlight.js');
    marked.setOptions({
      renderer: new marked.Renderer(),
      highlight: function (code: any) {
        return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
      },
      langPrefix: 'hljs language-', // highlight.js css expects a top-level 'hljs' class.
      pedantic: false,
      gfm: true,
      breaks: false,
      sanitize: false,
      smartLists: true,
      smartypants: false,
      xhtml: true
    });
    let html$ = of(marked.parse(markdownString));
    return await firstValueFrom(html$)
      .then(value => value.toString());
  }

  private async getMarkdownByPath(path: string): Promise<string> {
    // @ts-ignore
    let markdown$ = this.httpClient.get<string>(path, {responseType: "text"});
    return await firstValueFrom(markdown$)
      .then(value => value.toString());
  }

}
```